# How to replace certain characters of a string

Tags: java, android

- I have a string `@B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev\u00B6`
- I want to replace `\u00B6` with `¶`

**I tried with**

```
String comments="@B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev\u00B6";
comments=comments.replaceAll("\u00B6","¶");
```

- **Output**: `@B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev\u00B6`
- **Required Output**: `@B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev¶`

---

- ReplaceAll is not working
- How to make the required output

**Snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: When I try this on my machine it prints `@B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev¶`

Comment: Wrap the String in `Html.fromHtml()` and it'll parse for you. If it doesn't display properly, you don't have a supporting font.

Comment: Your code work for me

Comment: @GBlodgett and E. Betanzos .... Please check the snapshot I attached in debug mode

Comment: Your code works for me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u00B6` is a single character, with the Unicode code point of 0xB6; writing `\u00B6` is literally the same as writing ¶.

So, you need to escape the backslash: `\\`. Furthermore, backslashes are special in regular expressions, which replaceAll uses, so you need to escape it again -- and that escape needs to be escaped: `replaceAll("\\\\u00B6", "¶")`.

You could also use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) for that second level of escaping (the one for the regex): `replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\u00B6"), "¶")`.

Answer (score 0):

I get below example from http://techidiocy.com/replace-unicode-characters-from-java-string/ . I think it is work for u

```
public static StringBuffer removeUTFCharacters(String data){
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(\\p{XDigit}{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(data.length());
while (m.find()) {
String ch = String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16));
m.appendReplacement(buf, Matcher.quoteReplacement(ch));
}
m.appendTail(buf);
return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `StringEscapeUtils` provided by apache.

You can use it by adding following dependency:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.4'
```

**Code Sample:**

```
String comments="@B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev\u00B6";
Log.d("output", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(comments));
```

**Output:**

```
D/output: @B1AdGODG7:Devrath%Dev¶
```

This is the most reliable solution i have come across for this problem and have been using it for a while.